# Laravel w/ Docker - Safe for production?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, nginx

I recently spun up a Laravel / Docker environment by following [this digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose), and was just wondering if anybody sees any concerns with using this in a production environment? If there are concerns, could you perhaps explain why they are a concern and what I can do to circumvent them?

I would have asked the question in the tutorial comments instead, but that never gets enough visibility.

EDIT: Here are the `docker-compose.yml`, `Dockerfile` and `.env` files, just so you have a little more context without having to visit the tutorial. Let me know if you need anything else.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./.docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: laravel_root_password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    default-mysql-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    nano \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# */ 

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

`.env`:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:000/000000000000000000000000000000000000000=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://example.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=laraveluser
DB_PASSWORD=your_laravel_db_password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: `APP_KEY=base64:000/000000000000000000000000000000000000000=` looks suspiciously unsafe... You should be generating one..

Comment: It's just a placeholder so I wasn't sharing my actual key.

Comment: *"It's just a placeholder so I wasn't sharing my actual key"* fair enough i called it like i saw it at the time as a heads up warning..

Answer (score 3):

About a year ago, I deployed a Laravel app using Docker on an Ubuntu host.  We've had no issues.  Having a homogeneous environment eases team development and has helped streamline continuous deployment.

The production docker environment includes:

- PHP
- NGINX
- MySQL
- Redis

Additionally, the local docker environment includes:

- Mailhog
- A 'toolbox' that includes npm, mysql-client and other tools that would make things more convenient for the team.

There's a chance you'll want different docker-compose configurations for development vs. production.  You can manage this by creating a `docker-compose.prod.yml` file and have your CD pipeline overwrite `docker-compose.yml` with the `prod` version upon deployment.

Or, if no CD is in place, you could use a `docker-compose.dev.yml` file to overwrite production values and add new configurations. 
Then run

```
docker-compose up -d -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml
```

Good luck!